# how to get a point x amount distance down an imaginary line formed by a point and a direction

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have a Vector3f with 3 coords for the direction the player is looking on a 3d plane. And i also have a vector where the player is at. How can i get a point x far down the imaginary line formed by the vector and the direction? Any help is appriciated.

EDIT
heres what one of the responders said to do

```
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    float d = 5;

    Vector3f p = Camera.rotation;
    Vector3f v = Camera.vector;

    float mag = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p.x,2) + Math.pow(p.y,2) + Math.pow(p.z,2));
    Vector3f normalized = new Vector3f(p.x/mag,p.y/mag,p.z/mag);

    Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3(v.x,v.y,v.z);
    Vector3 dir1 = new Vector3(normalized.x,normalized.y,normalized.z);

    Vector3 hh = pos1.add(dir1.scale(d));

    x = hh.x;
    y = hh.y;
    z = hh.z;
```

EDIT2

i have realized that there is no z-axis in the rotation since it is in 360* for the side rotation. help?

Answer (score 0):

For clarity I'll change your question so that the distance is not `x` but `d`.

Let the player position coordinates be `px, py, pz`

Let the viewing direction be `vx, vy, vz`

Let `h` the hypotenuse of your view direction vector be

```
h = sqrt (vx*vx + vy*vy + vz*vz);
```

The coordinates of the target point `tx, ty, tz` will be

```
tx = px + d * vx / h;
ty = py + d * vy / h;
tz = pz + d * vz / h;
```

There is no need to normalise the view direction vector.

Comment: neither your or the other guys worked properly. they both returned the vector at a point above my head with barely any rotation

Comment: In that case, since two similar answers didn't work, you had better post the code showing how you implemented them.

Comment: I put @The Sockmonster's numbers into my solution and got his result. It *looks* as though your post will give the same. Have you tried a little standalone with the same numbers? In other words, have you made sure you know whether your error is coming from the calculation, or from what you do with its result?

Comment: i think i found the problem. i debugged it and the z vector for the rotation isnt getting updated

Comment: i dont know how to fix it though. im unsure of where to get the z axis from.

Comment: So I thought about it and I don't think there is a z rotation in 3d since the x goes 360 degrees. Is there a new method I can try knowing this?

Comment: If you are using a rotation matrix you might not see what is actually happening when you rotate the axis frame for a point x,y,z. Expressed geometrically, if you rotate the axes anticlockwise around the z-axis by an angle A then `x' = x cos A - y sin A` and `y' = y cos A + x sin A` and `z' = z` but wouldn't it be obvious that nothing will change in the z-direction?

Comment: where would the coordinate show up relative to the base coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a point in the distance along the line that the player is facing from their current position you should first normalize the direction vector (divide it by it's magnitude) if it isn't already, then multiply that by the distance you want to go and finally add the players position.

```
Normalize Vector
----------------
v = [3, 6, 2]
mag = sqrt(3^2 + 6^2, 2^2) = 7
v_normalized = [3/7, 6/7, 2/7] = [0.43, 0.86, 0.29]
```

So for example:

```
pos = [2, 1, 5]
dir = [0.43, 0.86, 0.29]
dist = 9

distant_point = pos + dir*dist = [5.87, 8.74, 7.61]
```